# Prolog shift or rotate elements left

Tags: prolog

I need a relation in prolog to shift list left rotationally by one element such that

```
shift([a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h],3,Shifted).
```

should produce

```
Shifted = [d,e,f,g,h,a,b,c]
```

could you help me?

this what I have

```
shift([], []).
shift([H|T], L) :-
   append(T, [H], L).

shift(0, L, L) :- !.
shift(N, L1, L2) :-
   N1 is N-1,
   shift(L1, L),
   shift(N1, L, L2).
```

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you specifically having a problem?

Comment: By *one* element or by *n* elements? Hint: Cut the head, append to tail.

Comment: I added what I have

Comment: its say Design a predicate shift/3 that “shifts” or “rotates” a list N places to the left. N may be a negative number, i.e. rotate to the right. Your predicate should have the signature shift(+List, +Integer, +List). Note that the rotated list should be the same length as the original list.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There might be more effective solutions, but the beautiful thing about Prolog, that you can use it *logically* rather than *imperatively*.

What is this shifting logically? A shift of the list `L1=Lx || Ly` by `N` positions is giving the list `L2=Ly || Lx` such that the length of `Lx` is exactly `N`. (*Note*: Here `||` denotes concatenation). How we translate it to Prolog? Straightforward:

```
shift(L1, N, L2) :- 
    append(Lx, Ly, L1), % L1 is Lx || Ly
    append(Ly, Lx, L2), % L2 is Ly || Lx
    length(Lx, N).      % The length of Lx is N
```

***Update:*** There is an additional requirement for negative `N` was stated by the OP in the comments. For that case an extension of the above is needed. It can be modified such that the actual left-shifting position would be the total list length minus the number of the positions:

```
shift(L1, N, L2) :-
    N < 0, !,             % this is the case for negative N
    length(L1, Len),
    N1 is Len + N,
    shift(L1, N1, L2).  

shift(L1, N, L2) :- 
    append(Lx, Ly, L1), % L1 is Lx || Ly
    append(Ly, Lx, L2), % L2 is Ly || Lx
    length(Lx, N).      % The length of Lx is N
```

Note that both implementations are working only for N not exceeding the length of the list. If you want to handle the cases it is, you will have to truncate `N` by modulus the length of the list.

***Update 2:***
I have actually realized that the negative case can be implemented much more consisely. It is just the same as swapping the sign and L1 with L2. So the specific case can be replaced with the following

```
shift(L1, N, L2) :-
    N < 0, !,
    N1 is -N,
    shift(L2, N1, L1).
```

Comment: you mean shift not shifted ?

Comment: when I changed to shift is working with me but when I try this one.                  shift([a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h],-2,Shifted). gave me error length/2: Domain error: `not_less_than_zero' expected, found `-2'

Comment: This requirement was not in the question. I am working to add it to the answer

Comment: oh yah sorry I forget to add it

Comment: Thanks a lot for explnation everything clearly  , I really thank you sir

Comment: @DanielLyons ok sorry I will delete my comment, I just need his help , anyway thanks

Comment: @user8286060 On that question you have all the help you need, now you need to apply the advice you got, study, try again, and then ask for followup help.

Comment: @lurker Yeah, forgot to remove it.

Comment: @EugeneSh. I need your help for my another question but MR Daniel don't want me to ask you here

Comment: @user8286060 If you have some unanswered question, it is probably because there is something wrong with the question itself. People here are willing to help if the question is good. There are many Prolog experts here, and I am not even of the top-100 I guess. So your best bet would be to either improve the existing question or ask a new one.

Comment: @EugeneSh. The reason why I am asking you because you explain everything clear and I didn't understand the another answer, anyway thanks a lot brother and I really appreciate you